# Output simple static value Angular

Tags: angular, output

I have looked quite some time into output from angular, but everywhere I only find a way to emit events. In my case, I have a parent with a router inside, and I wish to change the title based on a value from the child. So when I load route 1 I was thinking to emit a string via ngOnInit, but this doesn't work. I get the feeling that the way I want to accomplish this is not how it's supposed to be done. Any advice? The data is static and won't change in the child. Should I do an ngIf in the parent instead and check for the route?

```
<div> here i want the title 
  <router-outlet> <router-outlet>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service to share date between components.

Create a [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) in a service and subscribe to it in the main component. Using a `Subject` it's better than `BehaviorSubject` because doesn't emit a [initial value](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject).

Use this observable to emit the new title from each child component.

*app.service.ts*

```
 ...
 titleChanged$ = new Subject<string>();

 constructor() {}

 getTitleChanged$() {
   return this.titleChanged$.asObservable();
 }

 setTitle(title: string) {
   this.titleChanged$.next(title);
 }
 ...
```

*app.component.ts*

```
  ...
  this.appService
      .getTitleChanged$()
      .pipe(delay(0))
      .subscribe((title) => {
        this.title = title;
      });
  ...
```

I've created a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-title-from-child?file=src/app/app.service.ts)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The Stackblitz is not reachable for me, but I will try this approach!

Comment: I've fixed the link. It works.

Comment: Okay, perfect :) Thank you. This seems to be simple, but I will try to understand it better!

Comment: Instead of using a (title: string), use an array. Is the same process. The only thing you have to change "string" to the type of the array or simply "any" and change the way you use the variable title in the main component to print the title in the template.

Comment: I have got it to work :) I had to watch out for the types and then it worked. Wish you a great day.

Comment: I thought I already did. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

two options:

1. you can listen to the route change in the parent component, and change the
   title according to it.
2. you can store the title in a variable in some service as `behaviorSubject` and change its value from the child component, and listen to it in the parent component.